# pyodbc not recognising parameter placeholder in multi-line string

Tags: python, pyodbc

Why is pyodbc throwing this error:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

When I do have a parameter marker in the query?

It seems it only complains when I use a multiline string in python.

i.e. this is causing an error:

```
sql = """
SELECT a.r_object_id, a.object_name, a.document_status, a.document_id, a.document_status, b.r_version_label, a.r_link_cnt  
from pharma_document_sp a, pharma_document_rp b where a.r_object_id = b.r_object_id  and b.r_version_label = 'LATEST APPROVED' and a.document_id = ?
"""


cursor_cara.execute(sql, doc_id)
```

But this is OK:

```
sql = "SELECT a.r_object_id, a.object_name, a.document_status, a.document_id, a.document_status, b.r_version_label, a.r_link_cnt  "

sql = sql + " from pharma_document_sp a, pharma_document_rp b where a.r_object_id = b.r_object_id  and b.r_version_label = 'LATEST APPROVED' and a.document_id = ?"


cursor_cara.execute(sql, doc_id)
```

I am using:
pyodbc version 4.0.27,  SQL ODBC Server Driver 17,  Python 3.7.4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50226243/pyodbc-programmingerror-the-sql-contains-0-parameter-markers-but-3-parameter pyodbc uses ?, not %s, as the parameter placeholder.

Comment: I am using ?, see the code?  The issue is string concatenation to build the SQL works, the same code using multiline string doesn't work.  cx_oracle works fine using bind parameters (:parameter) over multiline string.

Comment: Wild guess: Maybe the trailing `\n` is a problem? What happens if you add a space after the `?` in your multiline string?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue using Python 3.8.1, pyodbc 4.0.30, and ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server. Please [edit] your question to include the versions you are using.

Comment: Added version details of pyodbc etc.